# Filtering a file in mac terminal

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal, data-science

I'm a complete novice at this, sorry if the tags aren't correct I'm not completely sure on the differences between a mac terminal and unix/linux.

I'm working on a textfile on my mac terminal.

I'm trying to filter column 4 so that only rows with  ***John*** are shown. Then exporting the 3rd row to a csv.

example:

```
1 | 11/11/11 | 8:01 | John was here<br/>
2 | 12/11/11 | 8:02 | Derek was here<br/>
3 | 13/11/11 | 8:03 | John was also here<br/>
4 | 14/11/11 | 8:04 | Bob was here<br/>
```

So far I've only managed to export the value I'm looking to filter by...

```
cut -f 4 Data_File_Name | grep -o "John" | sort -r > Export_CSV_File.csv
```

I'm missing the fundamentals of showing the data that only has John whilst only exporting a specific column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is `|` a delimiter or you've just shown for clarity here ?  Your question is not very clear, please add sample output too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are approaching it the right way, but there's a couple of problems.

The default delimiter to `cut` is the tab character, so you need to tell it to use `|`: `cut -d '|' -f 4 Data_File_Name`

This will give you:

```
 John was here
 Derek was here
 John was also here
 Bob was here
```

Note the extra space before each line. You can remove this if you want with `cut -c 2-`

The `-o` flag to grep will cause it to only output the part of the line that matched. If you want the full column, you should omit this flag: `grep "John"`

Combined:

`cut -d '|' -f 4 Data_File_Name | cut -c 2- | grep "John" | sort -r`

```
John was here
John was also here
```

Edit:
if you are using tab as the delimiter, and there are no leading spaces before and after the tabs (as there were around the pipes `|`):

`cut -f 4 Data_File_Name | grep "John" | sort -r`

Comment: I forgot to mention that the delimiter in the textfile are tabs

Comment: In that case, don't include `-d '|'` and it should work fine. You also might not need the `cut -c 2-` part if the tabs don't have spaces after them.

Comment: Hey tom how would I go about showing only the times for the rows with john in it? I tried adding | sort -k 3 > Export_File_CSV.csv but that didnt work

Comment: You could grep for John first, then use cut to get the column you want.

Comment: I tried doing: grep "john" | cut -f 3 Data_File > Export_File.csv However the output data was massive. Don't think it properly filtered.

Comment: You need to pass the file to grep rather than cut: `grep "john" Data_File | cut -f 3`

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot Tom, bloody life saver.